# Console log flooded with "discoveryd: Basic Warn DD_Warn: Bad count; corrupt NSEC RDATA"

Tags: console, macos

My console log is flooded with the message

```
discoveryd[51]: Basic Warn DD_Warn: Bad count; corrupt NSEC RDATA
```

They appear in bunches of many identical messages within only a few seconds, separated by short pauses (some seconds to some ten seconds).

I have a feeling that this started with updating Mavericks to Yosemite, but I cannot be sure as I am a fairly new Mac user for about half a year and am only now discovering the depths of the system.

Looking up the problem on Google seems to be extremely difficult as the msg string appears as an occasional side effect in many posted logs that discuss other topics.

My current system is 10.10.1